# How to enable the occurs check in all unifications in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, occurs-check

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occurs_check):

> Implementations offering sound unification for all unifications are Qu-Prolog and Strawberry Prolog and (optionally, via a runtime flag): XSB, **SWI-Prolog** and Tau Prolog.

However, when I do `apropos(occur)` it only finds `unify_with_occurs_check/2`. The *man* page doesn't mention "occur" either. How can the occurs check be enabled for all unifications in SWI-Prolog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the section on [*Environment Control*](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=flags), it lists the flags of the system. The `occurs_check` flag is the one that controls occurs checks for unification.

You can set the flag with:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
```

For example:

```
?- X = f(X).
X = f(X).

?- set_prolog_flag(occurs_check, true).
true.

?- X = f(X).
false.
```

So first it unifies `X` with `f(X)`. If we later set the `occurs_check` to `true`, then if we try to unify `X` again with `f(X)`, it fails.